# Ruby - include? related issue

Tags: ruby

Could anyone help me with getting to the core of the mistake contained in the following code line?

```
main_frame.html.include? =~ /Your credit card does not have any statements|No activity is found in your credit card/i
```

Comment: Do you get an error? And is the line break after "any" intentional?

Comment: I am getting a nil on a page where one of the expressions is presented, and the result should be a figure. Breaking of the line relates to formatting here on Stackoverflow

Comment: What is (the result of) `main_frame.html` and what is the expression supposed to return?

Comment: It's just a frame, it is supposed to return "true" as the second expression is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the following:

```
!!(main_frame.html =~ /Your credit card does not have any statements|No activity is found in your credit card/i)
```

or

```
!!(/Your credit card does not have any statements|No activity is found in your credit card/i.match main_frame.html)
```

or (using `include?` but no regexp)

```
[
  'Your credit card does not have any statements', 
  'No activity is found in your credit card'
].any? do |t| 
  main_frame.html.include? t
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling two methods `include?` and `=~`. The former takes an argument, so it cannot become the argument of `=~`.

Comment: Just read the docs on these methods and you'll become enlightened ;).

Comment: @guitarfreak `=~` _is_ a method call. Removing `include?` should work, i.e. `main_frame.html =~ /.../i`. You can probably also use `match` or `match?` _instead of_ (not in addition to) `=~`, depending on the context.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much, that is indeed the problem with my understanding.